# Sign into pbi to see report via url link

Tags: python, authentication, logging, powerbi

I need to use python to open a power bi link and screenshot its pages. While trying to create the scrip I get an error where AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_id' and this opens chrome app.powerbi.com/singleSignOn page which means I have to write my email in the page and click submit. I need to find a way that python can use my local information or I can provide my information to auto sign in to get access to the report.

Is there a way to access pbi in an enterprise that requires you to log in to access the pbi links?

This is my code:

```
import csv
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from pdfkit import PDFKit

def get_report_pages(link, num_pages):
    
    driver = Chrome()
    driver.get(link)

    for i in range(1, num_pages + 1):
        # Get the report container element
        report_container = driver.find_element_by_id("reportContainer")

        # Get the screenshot of the report container
        screenshot = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()

        # Crop the screenshot to only the report page
        cropped_screenshot = screenshot.crop((
            report_container.location["x"],
            report_container.location["y"],
            report_container.size["width"],
            report_container.size["height"]
        ))

        # Save the screenshot
        with open("report_page_" + str(i) + ".png", "wb") as f:
            f.write(cropped_screenshot)

    driver.quit()

def create_pdf_report(report_name, images):
    pdfkit.from_file(images, report_name + ".pdf")

def main():
    with open(r'''C:\Users\email_links_subscriptions.csv''', "r") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            link = row["link"]
            num_pages = int(row["num_pages"])
            get_report_pages(link, num_pages)
            report_name = row["report_name"]
            images = [f"report_page_{i}.png" for i in range(1, num_pages + 1)]
            create_pdf_report(report_name, images)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```